# Changing the refresh rate of a monitor from Ctrl+Alt+F1

Tags: linux

So, I changed a refresh rate which shouldn’t of been changed. And so I’m using Ctrl+Alt+F1 to try and reset those settings (before login) on Kali Linux. Problem is, now when I use `xrandr`, it says “Can’t open display”. Anyway to reset all monitor settings from Ctrl+Alt+F1?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer here! Works for Kali too, and probably a few other distros other than Ubuntu, but here's a solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/410688/1049913